# How to download a binary large file throw HTTPS when the web server require a client TLS certificate?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I didn't find any way to implement an SSLContext with DownloadManager. Is there a way to add a Client certificate (keystore)?

For now, it is a self signed certificate (both client&server). I'm able to connect to this server with okhttp (managing SSLContext) but with DownloadManager i get an error 'SSL Handshake'.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code,

```
 @Nullable
private static SSLContext initTrustManager(Context context) {
    try {
        CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("s_cert.cer");
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = certificateFactory.generateCertificate(is);
            Log.i("TrustManager", "ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        return sslContext;
    } catch (CertificateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And here is how  I implement it:

```
builder.sslSocketFactory(initTrustManager(context).getSocketFactory());
```

This is working code, so if you still get exceptions, pay attention to SSL certificate itself or make some changes inside api of server. Hope it helps))

Comment: I edited my question according to your answer. Thank you.